# C++ Template Class definition getting error

Tags: c++, templates

I am learning C++ templates.I created a template class for addition of two strings
but I'm getting folloing error: Please help me to understand this error.

`main.cc:65:52: error: no matching function for call to TheNameHolder<std::basic_string<char> >::TheNameHolder(const char [8], const char [7])`

```
using namespace std;

template <class T>
class TheNameHolder{
    T *a, *b;
    public:
    TheNameHolder(T *first, T *last)
    {
    a= first;
    b= last;
   }
   T getName();
};

template <class T>
T TheNameHolder<T> :: getName()
{
    T returnVal;
    returnVal = strcat (returnVal,a);
    returnVal = strcat (returnVal, " ");
    returnVal = strcat (returnVal, b);
    return returnVal;

}


int main()
{

    TheNameHolder <string> obj ("Hi", "");
    cout << obj.getName ();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: you declare parameters in your constructor as pointers to T, but you pass strings as arguments in main. Try to change your paramters type to const &T

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What? No. This isn't what templates are used for

You use `strcat` on your templated objects (actually, on `T*`, so on pointers to your object)

`strcat` accepts only `char *`. So `T` has to be char for it to work. If you know `T` is `char`, then it isn't a template as you know what it is. (btw - you have another bug that `returnval` should be `T*`, and you are using it uninitialized)

You seem to miss the whole concept of templates - which is OK since you are learning.

See - the sentence "I want to use templates to add two strings" is wrong - as you don't have any unknowns! You want to add 2 strings, you know what your type is. It isn't template.

Template would be "I want to add two lists of an unknown type" (then you can't use `strcat` obviously, nor can you assume your lists are "zero delimited" as that is only true for c style strings).

Answer (score 3):

Your template parameter is `std::string`, so your constructor

```
TheNameHolder(T *first, T *last)
```

expects two pointers to `std::string`. You are passing it const arrays of `char` (string literals). It seems to me you can express everything in terms of `std::string`:

```
template <class T>
class TheNameHolder{
    T a, b;
    public:
    TheNameHolder(const T& first, const T& last) : a(first), b(last)
    {
    }
    T getName() { return a + " " + b; }
};

int main()
{
    TheNameHolder<std::string> obj("Hi", "");
    std::cout << obj.getName();
}
```

Note it isn't completely clear whether you need a class template here. The only advantage of this is that you can also use `std::wstring` or any other string type that supports initialization from a string literal and the `+` operator.

Comment: This may just be my ignorance regarding namespaces, but, since he's using "namespace std", wouldn't his <string> be assumed to be <std::string>?

Comment: @BenC. Yes, that is my assumption. My code differs because I never `using namespace std`, and am in the habit of qualifying standard library types with the `std::` namespace. Oh, maybe you got confused by my badly spelt `std::wstring`.

Answer (score 0):

As was stated above, this would be the wrong place to use templates since you already know the data type. However, in the case where you may actually wish to "add two lists of an unknown type", you can use template specializations to deal with specific (in this case non-numeric) data types such as strings.
You would specialize this template as follows:

`template <>
class TheNameHolder <std::string> {
...
};`